# Javascript - Array.prototype.slice.call causing performance issues

Tags: javascript, performance

`prototype.slice.call( array, 0 )` in one of the Jquery files.
Page basically brings up a parent-child kind of search results.
This script gets executed when user clicks on the link adjoining parent to see the list of children under it.

The issue we are facing is that while executing this script browser complains 
"A script on this browser is causing it to run slow" 
and it points to this script and the line below :

```
array = Array.prototype.slice.call( array, 0 );
```

Please let me know if there is any alternative to this.

Comment: Is `array` a jQuery set here ?

Comment: slice() is a native method, not sure how you can optimize that. Maybe the problem is in the array itself?

Comment: Show us the stack trace, and the code from where this jQuery thing is called. Array `slice` is certainly not the reason for the long-running script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a jQuery set to an array, you should use the provided [get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) function :

```
array = array.get();
```

Note that internally jQuery uses `slice` without the `0` index. It's equivalent to

```
array = [].slice.call(array);
```

Comment: Hi dystroy,When I replaced 'Array.prototype.slice.call( array, 0 )'with 'array  =  array.get();' I am not seeing any search results. So this is not working. Is there anything else I can do ?